# Create a WPF RawStylusInput event?

Tags: c#, wpf, inkcanvas, stylus-pen

I have a custom hardware device, which reports some coordinates through custom API.

**What I wanted**

I want to show hardware coordinates on WPF as ink, in real-time.

**My thoughts**

Reading [Creating an Ink Input Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/creating-an-ink-input-control?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8),
I think translating hardware coordinate to a WPF stylus event, and send to my specific `InkCanvas` control is one method.

But I'm stuck at first step, attempting to raise stylus event to my `StylusPlugIn` at creating a `RawStylusInput` object, which has an `internal` only constructor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you not just manually create Strokes and StylusPoints? E.g. as done here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69727747/1136211

Comment: @Clemens I'm currently using that method, but have performance issue on low-end computers, because Strokes must be added on the UI thread. I would like to directly inject on the Pen thread.